# How to pass variable names as a parameter in android studio

Tags: java, android, list, methods, parameters

Is it possbile to pass variable names as parameters in java/android studio? I have a method:

```
   private void Data(Something something ) {

        List<String> something = new ArrayList<>();
        something.add("Data");

    }
```

and I would like to pass the name of the list 'something' as parameter in for the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can pass all types of data to a method/function in Java/android!

But you can not define same `variable` name twice in the same scope! 
E.G: `Global variable` more than once inside same class!  or `Local variable` more than once in the same `method`.

```
 private void data(List<String> something) {
// convention is to write first letter of function in lower case and Class name in upper case.

        something2= something;       
        something2.add("Data");

    }
```

call this method like this.

```
List<String> something = new ArrayList<>();
data(something);
```

Comment: it underlines Something  in red

Comment: which part is causing red ? what does it say

Comment: in this line private void data(Something something ) it underlines the first Something in red saying 'cannot resolve symbol 'Something''

Comment: i have updated the answer please check. (`Something something` was just an Example)

Answer (score 0):

No.  To a limited degree you can with reflection.  But unless you're doing one of a small list of things, the need to do that usually means you need to fix your architecture.